# issue with javascript in aspx file

Tags: javascript

here is my code in aspx file...

> function updateuserstatus(arg) {
>               //../images/approved.jpg" : "../images/rejected.jpg"
>
> ```
>         var datauserid = $(arg).attr('data-userid');
>         var curStatus = $(arg).attr('data-status');
>         var upmstatus = (curStatus.toString().toLowerCase() == 'false' ? true : false);
>
>         $.ajax({
>             type: "POST",
>             url: "Login.aspx/updatematerialstat",
>             data: '{status: "' + upmstatus + '", id:"' + datauserid + '" }',
>             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>             dataType: "json",
>             success: function (msg) {
>                 if (msg.d) {
>
>                     var srcd = upmstatus ? "../admin/images/icn_alert_success.png" :
> ```
>
> "../admin/images/icn_alert_error.png";
>                           $("#img" + datauserid + "").attr("src", srcd);
>                           $(arg).attr('data-status', upmstatus);
>                       }
>                   },
>                   failure: function (response) {
>                       alert(response.d);
>                   }
>               });
>           }
>
> ```
> <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999"
>     BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
>     OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" BorderStyle="Solid" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
>     CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" Height="100px" Width="602px" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
>     AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
>     onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
>     <Columns>
>         <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsActive">
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkisactive" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Isactive") %>' />
>                 &nbsp;
>             </ItemTemplate>
>             <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
>             <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
>         </asp:TemplateField>--%>
>         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
>                     CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton>
>             </ItemTemplate>
>         </asp:TemplateField>
>
>         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FName">
>             <EditItemTemplate>
>                 &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lbleditid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
>                 <asp:Label ID="lblfname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Firstname") %>'></asp:Label>
>             </EditItemTemplate>
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 <asp:Label ID="lblfnameitem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Firstname") %>'></asp:Label>
>                 &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lbluserid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
>             </ItemTemplate>
>             <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
>             <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
>         </asp:TemplateField>
>         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LName">
>             <EditItemTemplate>
>                 <asp:Label ID="lbllastname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Lastname") %>'></asp:Label>
>             </EditItemTemplate>
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
>                 <asp:Label ID="lbllnameitem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Lastname") %>'></asp:Label>
>                 &nbsp;
>             </ItemTemplate>
>             <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
>             <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
>         </asp:TemplateField>
>         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Usertype">
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 <asp:Label ID="lblusertype" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Usertype") %>'></asp:Label>
>             </ItemTemplate>
>         </asp:TemplateField>
>         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
>             <EditItemTemplate>
>                 <asp:Label ID="lblemailid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailID") %>'></asp:Label>
>             </EditItemTemplate>
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 &nbsp;&nbsp;
>                 <asp:Label ID="lblemailitem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailID") %>'></asp:Label>
>                 &nbsp;
>             </ItemTemplate>
>             <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
>             <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
>         </asp:TemplateField>
>         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
>             <EditItemTemplate>
>                 <asp:Label ID="lblcity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>'></asp:Label>
>             </EditItemTemplate>
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 <asp:Label ID="lblcityitem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>'></asp:Label>
>                 &nbsp;
>             </ItemTemplate>
>             <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
>             <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
>         </asp:TemplateField>
>         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State">
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 <asp:Label ID="lblstate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("State") %>'></asp:Label>
>             </ItemTemplate>
>         </asp:TemplateField>
>         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 <asp:Label ID="lbladdress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>'></asp:Label>
>             </ItemTemplate>
>         </asp:TemplateField>
>         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone">
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 <asp:Label ID="lblphone" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Phone") %>'></asp:Label>
>             </ItemTemplate>
>         </asp:TemplateField>
>          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve">
>            <ItemTemplate>
>                     <a href="javascript:;" data-status="<%#Eval("Isactive") %>" data-userid="<%#Eval("ID") %>"
>                         onclick="updateuserstatus(this);">&nbsp;
>                         <img id='img<%#Eval("ID") %>' src='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Isactive")) ?
> ```
>
> "../admin/images/icn_alert_success.png" :
>   "../admin/images/icn_alert_error.png" %>'
>                                   height="20px" width="20px" />
>                           
>                       
>                   
>                   
>               
>               
>                   
>                       
>                   
>                   
>                   
>               
>               
>                   
>                       '>

and following is the webmethod...

> [WebMethod]
>       public static bool updatematerialstat(bool status, int id)
>       {
>           bool res = false;
>           try
>           {
>               user.Operation obj = new user.Operation();
>               if (obj.ustatus(status, id))
>               { res = true; }
>           }
>           catch (Exception ex)
>           {
>               throw ex;
>           }
>           return res;
>       }

now in browser it is giving following error...

> "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

any solution....???

Comment: Most likely you haven't referenced jQuery for that page...

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in your "head" section of the page where you defines the reference to the css files and .js files.:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

"ReferenceError: $ is not defined" error comes when you missed to provide the reference to the jQuery min file.